# C type representation in abstract syntax tree (AST)

Tags: c, types, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

I am implementing a C compiler and I am struggling to find a good way of representing an expression's type in the AST. Is there a standard way of doing this? I thought about implementing it as a linked list, but I think it would be kind of wasteful.

Comment: Implement it as a tree.

Comment: [langdev.se] may be a better place to ask questions like this.